# How to implement mocha like optional async callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I would like to implement optional async callbacks in same way as the mocha does.

I mean that I want to have callback function which can be both sync and async.

When user uses optional callback parameter 'done' it's async, when there is no callback parameter than it's synchronous.

```
// Sync version
it('does something sync', function() { 
  console.log('this is sync version') 
});

// Async version
it('does something async, function(done) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    done(true);
  }, 1000);
});
```

How can function 'it' distinguish if the callback is sync or async?

Any idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can assume that the `toString` of your function hasn't been overridden, you could use it on a user-defined function to check if it has an argument named `done`, for example:

```
function argIndexOf(f, arg) {
  var s = f + '';
  return s.substring(s.indexOf('(') + 1, s.indexOf(')'))
    .replace(/\s+/g, '').split(',').indexOf(arg);
}

argIndexOf(function(){}, 'done'); // -1
argIndexOf(function(done){}, 'done') // 0
argIndexOf(function(arg1, done){}, 'done') // 1
```

That function would take in a function as an argument and return the position of it's `done` argument, or `-1` if there is none. It uses [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), which will need to be [shimmed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill) if you want to use it in IE 8 or earlier. You've tagged the question `node.js`, so I will assume that is not an issue.

You could even add it to Function.prototype, although this is highly discouraged if you want your code to play well with others:

```
Function.prototype.indexOf = Function.prototype.indexOf || function(arg) {
  var s = this + '';
  return s.substring(s.indexOf('(') + 1, s.indexOf(')'))
    .replace(/\s+/g, '').split(',').indexOf(arg);
};
```

Then you could just use:

```
func.indexOf('done')
```

You can also use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and it will ignore negative indices, so to call the callback and pass in a value for 'done':

```
var args = [];
args[func.indexOf('done')] = done_callback;
func.apply(func, args);
```

Comment: Really neat trick. Probably I will stick with this. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @korCZis Thanks, and no problem :) @mscdex's answer is correct though, Mocha doesn't test that your argument is actually named `done`, it just checks if there is at least `1` argument, and it doesn't break if `Function.prototype.toString` has been overridden.

Answer (score 8):

Mocha only [checks](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/blob/master/lib/runnable.js#L43) for the existance of a callback parameter in the test function. `function.length` is used to determine how many parameters there are for the callback.

Comment: +1 and further down on line 179 is how mocha handles the `done()`. https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/blob/master/lib/runnable.js#L179

Comment: Fantastic, I did not know that `function.length` is mapped to the arguments count. Very clean!